# Matplotlib returns a blank plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a list that stores various pandas data frames. I intend to print a single data frame from the list, however the plot obtained is empty.

```
import pandas as pd
Y6= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]     
Y6=pd.DataFrame(data=Y6)
dfs = list()
for x in range(0, len(Y6), 10):
   df = Y6.iloc[x:x+10].T
   #df.columns= ['one','two']
   dfs.append(df)

for df in dfs:
   print(df)
   print()
print(dfs[0])
plt.plot(dfs[0])
#Obtained output 
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190f81710>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190f81908>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190f81b00>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190f81cf8>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190f81ef0>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190eef128>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190eef320>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190eef518>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190eef710>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1f190eef908>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of plotting one line with 10 points, you plot 10 lines with one point per line. Since a line need to consist of two points at least, nothing is shown on the plot.

Consider not transposing your dataframe, such that it stays a single column. Then plotting works as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Y6= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]     
Y6=pd.DataFrame(data=Y6)
dfs = list()
for x in range(0, len(Y6), 10):
   df = Y6.iloc[x:x+10]
   dfs.append(df)

plt.plot(dfs[0])

plt.show()
```